# Scala REPL in an Android app

Tags: android, scala

I've created an application that simulates the Scala REPL on Windows. The idea is to use it in an app on Android. But I understand the Scala REPL or Interpreter actually compiles the code and then generates bytecode. According to [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Scala-Interpreter-in-Android-td2000177.html) it's not possible to do it in Android because of the Dalvik bytecode(Android) vs Java bytecode (Scala) incompatibility. Is this true? Would appreciate it if anyone can point me to a working app/implementation as well if it exists.

PS: I've spent one day and one night trying to get this to work in an Android app. It has thrown a myriad of exceptions, restarted the emulator and crashed eclipse. Hence the question :(

Comment: "Is this true?" Yes. Unless, of course, you translate the byte code generated by Scala to dalvik bytecode. But it's probably easier to not run the REPL on Android.

Comment: Odd, looks like somebody deleted my comment, wonder what was so offensive in that. @KimStebel: Thanks for your comment, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What a pity! Did you try translating solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is this true?" Yes. Unless, of course, you translate the byte code generated by Scala to dalvik bytecode. But it's probably easier to not run the REPL on Android.