# Does scala have something similar to jython's standalone jar?

Tags: scala, jython

With jython's standalone jar you can do:

```
java -jar jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar
```

And the repl starts.

I'd like to do that with scala:

```
java -jar scala-standalone.jar
```

This would put me into the scala repl.

Let me ask this another way. 
How do you invoke the scala repl using 
java.

```
java -cp <jars> <class-with-main-method>
```

In paticular, I don't want to use the scala cli or even have it installed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for here... Scala _is_ a jar; repl, scripts, compiler, scaladoc -- they are all jar files.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a Scala-specific question. You can just as easily create a JAR file that will support `java -jar ...` for Java as for Scala. You just need to include the Scala standard library JARs.

Comment: @Daniel. Yes, scala is a jar etc, but I was just wondering if that was a jar bundled with everything you need and you could just start the repl using java. There is something like that for jython. You can either install jython, which is a repl, scripts, compiler, etc or you can just download the standalone jar and just use that. In the first case you use "jython ..." in the second case you use "java -jar jython.jar"

Comment: @Randall. I thought of it as a scala question because it involves the starting of a scala repl. Yes, it you can think of it as a java question as well, but then these categories are fuzzy. And in the end someone who looks for scala tagged questions is much more likely to be able to answer this question.  I know that one can make this happen. Just get the jars and do a java <main method of some class>,  and the repl would start. Jython provides an easy of doing this by providing a standalone jar that contains everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do it through `java -jar`, but my guess is it won't be as easy as jython. For example, if you look at `scala.bat` (on windows) in the standard install of scala, you will see that is using some variant of the following command:

```
"java" -Xmx256M -Xms32M -Dscala.home="C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\.." -Denv.emacs=""
-Dscala.usejavacp=true  -cp "C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\jline.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-actors.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-partest.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-reflect.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-swing.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scalacheck.jar;
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scalap.jar" scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner
```

All in one single line of course. I did a `cd` into the scala installation directory and then the `bin` folder and ran this command directly. It gave me a scala repl.

I'm guessing you can probably skip some of the jars (swing, actors etc), combine the rest into a single jar and get rid of some of the command line params and then kick it off using `java -jar myscala.jar`

PS: If you're trying to do something with android, beware it won't work. Because I've tried it before: [Scala REPL in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102702/scala-repl-in-an-android-app)

:D

Answer (score 2):

You could build one yourself if necessary. There is a [recent blog post](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/create-your-custom-scala-repl/) that shows you how to create a REPL. If you build that code with sbt and drop in the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, you should get a standalone REPL via `sbt assembly`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the scala script?

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scala.html

Comment: Yes, but with an cli that uses java directly and only a single jar. This is what jython provides. Yes, it's possible to put all this together by just combining the jars, but I liked the elegance and ease of use of the jython approach: just get a single jython jar and that's all you need.